# Azure: Setting up redirect from root domain to subdomain

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

In Azure I have added my custom domain say "something.com". The problem is I want to re-direct "something.com" to "www.something.com".

After researching it seems to that one can do this through Web.config parameters in Azure Devops.

I already have the following code setup there, can anyone tell me how to add the required parameter for redirect.

```
-Handler iisnode -NodeStartFile local.js -appType node
```

[image]

Comment: What the mean of `how to add the required parameter for redirect.`?

Comment: Azure devops has an option to generate web.config from parameters. Check the pic attached in the question

Answer (score 0):

You can use the URL rewrite in your web.config file to redirect your Azure Web Site subdomain to custom domain name. If you don’t have a web.config file, then you can create one under root directory. Check the below example code for URL redirect

```html
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>  
    <rewrite>  
        <rules>  
          <rule name="Redirect rquests to default azure websites domain" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />  
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
              <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^yoursite\.azurewebsites\.net$" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.yoursite.com/{R:0}" />  
          </rule>  
        </rules>  
    </rewrite>  
  </system.webServer>  
</configuration>
```

You can also add a CNAME record to map a subdomain to the app's default hostname. Refer [**Map an existing custom DNS name to Azure Web Apps**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain) and [**Mapping a custom subdomain to an Azure Website**](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/waws/2014/10/01/mapping-a-custom-subdomain-to-an-azure-website/)

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't answer the question as in Azure Devops the web.config file is automatically created.